# Apply font style only if the first font does not load

Tags: css, fonts

How can I apply a particular style to some text, only if the first font does not load?

Font 1 is bolder than font 2, in the case that font 1 does not load, I'd like to set the `font-weight` property for font 2.

Example:

```
#text{
    font-family: font1,font2;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight:bold; /* Only for font 2 */
}
```

JavaScript solutions are acceptable too.

Comment: Don't think you can do that with css. How about using a bolder version of font 2 instead as a fallback

Comment: @Webpandit That's what I'm going to have to resort to if I don't get any good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, what you want is not possible. But practically, it is.

**The bad news:** *you can't change `font-weight` property based on what `font-family` applies, using CSS. **Period.*** Actually, even with `JavaScript` that's not as easy as it seems, because `style.fontFamily` property does not change. It's still `font1,font2`, no matter which one applies.

**The good news:** *you don't have to change `font-weight` based on `font-family`!*. Use `@font-face` to define `font2` to point at the font files for the bold version of `font2` and define it with the same font-weight as `font1`, even if it's not the "real" one.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: font2;
  src: url("font2_Bold.ttf"); 
  /*...rest of required font files, eot, woff... all bold */
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Also note specifying multiple font-families is a thing of the past, back from the days when websites depended on fonts to be installed on the user's computer to apply.

Today, thanks to modern font formats and `@font-face`, this never happens anymore. The font file always loads, because it's provided by the website, it doesn't have to be installed on user's machine. So relax. Your `font2` will actually load in less than `0.5%` cases. And, usually, when a font file fails to load, chances are multiple other resources fail to load, meaning this is one of the smallest problems and a page reload is probably required to view it properly.

---

If the above is not an option or seems too complicated, you can always use the `load` event of any resource, including font files:

```js
function fontHasLoaded() {
  document.getElementById('test').style.fontWeight = 400;
}
```

```css
#test {
  font-family: 'Rubik-Mono-One', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;   
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik+Mono+One" rel="stylesheet" onload="fontHasLoaded()">

<span id="test">Inspect to see font-weight. Than change font link to a broken link and inspect again.</span>
```

Comment: thanks, but first, I'm going to check out the JQuery solution above.

Comment: You're welcome. Here's [the test](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/c93370p2/).

Comment: Right... well, I've tried to use your solution, but it doesn't seem to work. `font2` is actually a system installed font (Arial).

Comment: Can't you define `font1` with `font-weight: 900`? I'm assuming you know you need to take an `.otf` or `.ttf` having the desired font-weight and parse it through a [font-generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), right? In the generated `.css`, you just replace the font-weight with your own.

Comment: Nope, can't override any fonts with `@font-face`

Comment: I've updated my previous comment. Read it carefully. If you can't do it, you'll need to pay someone to do it. Because it's possible... Or just don't do it at all! In the end, as I already stated, we're talking an extremely low percent of users. I mean, your effort of writing this question is probably not worth it, never mind overriding a `font-weight` property of a `@font-face`... I'm probably the only nutcase to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be impossible if you want to do it only with css. Js could help.

```
if(ele.style.fontSize == font2){
    ele.style.fontWeight = xxx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery for this . for example

```
if ($("#text").css('font-family') === 'font2')
{
   $("#text").css({'font-weight': 'bold'});
}
```

Comment: This won't work since `font-family` just returns the fonts as declared in CSS, not the actual one used by the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by downloading required font.

first it will be in **ttf**

convert it to **woff** format [webfont-generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Robotoregular";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: local("Roboto Regular"), local("Roboto-Regular"), url("../fonts/roboto/roboto-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratbold';
    src: url('../fonts/Montserrat/montserrat-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Montserrat/montserrat-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

then apply style to specified

```
#text{
    font-family: 'Robotoregular','montserratbold';
    font-size: 40px;
}
```